# Large Margin Classifier with CVXOPT

Tags: machine-learning, svm, python

I need to generate a Large Margin Classifier using python library cvxopt which allows me to solve the quadratic program.

I am trying to write a python function to take the training data and some test data and return the support vectors and the distance of each test data point from the optimal hyperplane.
I am struggling, however, to understand the output of the cvxopt and how to use it to find the support vectors and then the distances.

My function so far looks like this:

```
def lmc(X, t, Xtest):

    numSamples = len(X)

    P = matrix(outer(t,t) * inner(X,X))
    q = matrix(ones(numSamples) * -1)

    G = matrix(diag(ones(numSamples) * -1))
    h = matrix(zeros(numSamples))

    A = matrix(t, (1,numSamples))
    b = matrix(0.0)

    solution = solvers.qp(P, q, G, h, A, b)

    return solution
```

The output of this function so far includes large vectors: s, x, z and a single value for y. My knowledge of support vector machines is pretty sketchy so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the notation and steps provided by [Tristan Fletcher](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58851af9ebbd1a30e98fb283/t/58902fbae4fcb5398aeb7505/1485844411772/SVM+Explained.pdf) the general steps to solve the SVM problem are the following. You can also see the full article and code in python [here](https://xavierbourretsicotte.github.io/SVM_implementation.html):

- Create $\mathbf{H}$ where $H_{i,j} = y^{(i)}y^{(j)} <x^{(i)} x^{(j)}> $. Note this is matrix $P$ in the CVXOPT API
- Calculate $\mathbf{w} = \sum_i^m y^{(i)} \alpha_i x^{(i)}$
- Determine the set of support vectors $S$ by finding the indices such that $\alpha_i > 0$
- Calculate the intercept term using $b = y^{(s)} - \sum_{m \in S} \alpha_m  y^{(m)}  <x^{(m)}  x^{(s)} >$
- For each new point $x'$ classify according to $y' = sign(w^T x' + b)$

---

### Re-writing the problem in an appropriate format

Since we will solve this optimization problem using the **[CVXOPT](https://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#quadratic-programming)** library in python we will need to match the solver's API which, according to the documentation is of the form:

\begin{aligned}
 & \min \frac{1}{2} x^TPx + q^Tx
 \\
  s.t. \ & \ Gx \leq h 
 \\
 & \ Ax = b
\end{aligned}

With API

> `cvxopt.solvers.qp(P, q[, G, h[, A, b[, solver[, initvals]]]])`

Recall that the dual problem is expressed as:

$$ \max_{\alpha} \sum_i^m \alpha_i - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j}^m y^{(i)}y^{(j)} \alpha_i \alpha_j <x^{(i)} x^{(j)}> $$

Let $\mathbf{H}$ be a matrix such that $H_{i,j} = y^{(i)}y^{(j)} <x^{(i)} x^{(j)}> $, then the optimization becomes:

\begin{aligned}
 & \max_{\alpha} \sum_i^m \alpha_i  - \frac{1}{2}  \alpha^T \mathbf{H}  \alpha
 \\
  s.t. & \ \alpha_i \geq 0 
 \\
 &  \ \sum_i^m \alpha_i y^{(i)} = 0 
\end{aligned}

We convert the sums into vector form and multiply both the objective and the constraint by $-1$ which turns this into a minimization problem and reverses the inequality

\begin{aligned}
 & \min_{\alpha}  \frac{1}{2}  \alpha^T \mathbf{H}  \alpha - 1^T \alpha
 \\
 & s.t. \ - \alpha_i \leq 0 
 \\
 & s.t. \ y^T \alpha = 0 
\end{aligned}

We are now ready to convert our numpy arrays into the cvxopt format, using the same notation as in the documentation this gives

- $P := H$  a matrix of size $m \times m$
- $q := - \vec 1$ a vector of size $m \times 1$
- $G : = - diag[1]$ a diagonal matrix of -1s of size $m \times m$
- $h : = \vec 0$ a vector of zeros of size $m \times 1$
- $A := y$ the label vector of size $m \times 1$
- $b := 0$ a scalar

Note that in the simple example of $m = 2$ the matrix $G$ and vector $h$ which define the constraint are

$G = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $ and $h = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} $

### Computing the matrix $\mathbf{H}$ in vectorized form

Consider the simple example with 2 input samples $\{x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}\} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ which are two dimensional vectors. i.e. $x^{(1)} = (x_1^{(1)} , x_2^{(1)})^T$

$$ X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1^{(1)} & x_2^{(1)} \\ x_1^{(2)} & x_2^{(2)} \end{bmatrix} \ \ \ y = \begin{bmatrix} y^{(1)}  \\ y^{(2)} \end{bmatrix} $$

We now proceed to creating a new matrix $X'$ where each input sample $x$ is multiplied by the corresponding output label $y$. This can be done easily in Numpy using vectorization and padding.

$$X' = \begin{bmatrix} x^{(1)}_1 y^{(1)} & x^{(1)}_2y^{(1)} \\
x^{(2)}_1y^{(2)} & x^{(2)}_2y^{(2)} \end{bmatrix} $$

Finally we take the **matrix multiplication** of $X'$ and its transpose giving $H = X'  X'^T$

$$H = X' @ X'^T = \begin{bmatrix} x^{(1)}_1 y^{(1)} & x^{(1)}_2y^{(1)} \\
x^{(2)}_1y^{(2)} & x^{(2)}_2y^{(2)} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x^{(1)}_1 y^{(1)} & x^{(2)}_1 y^{(2)}  \\
x^{(1)}_2y^{(1)} & x^{(2)}_2y^{(2)} \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ H = \begin{bmatrix}  x^{(1)}_1 x^{(1)}_1y^{(1)}y^{(1)} + x^{(1)}_2x^{(1)}_2y^{(1)}y^{(1)} & x^{(1)}_1 x^{(2)}_1y^{(1)}y^{(2)} + x^{(1)}_2x^{(2)}_2y^{(1)}y^{(2)} \\ x^{(2)}_1 x^{(1)}_1y^{(2)}y^{(1)} + x^{(2)}_2x^{(1)}_2y^{(2)}y^{(1)} & x^{(2)}_1 x^{(2)}_1y^{(2)}y^{(2)} + x^{(2)}_2x^{(2)}_2y^{(2)}y^{(2)} \end{bmatrix}$$

### Implementation in Python

#### Toy data set

```
#Data set
x_neg = np.array([[3,4],[1,4],[2,3]])
y_neg = np.array([-1,-1,-1])
x_pos = np.array([[6,-1],[7,-1],[5,-3]])
y_pos = np.array([1,1,1])
x1 = np.linspace(-10,10)
x = np.vstack((np.linspace(-10,10),np.linspace(-10,10)))

#Data for the next section
X = np.vstack((x_pos, x_neg))
y = np.concatenate((y_pos,y_neg))
```

#### CVXOPT solver and resulting $\alpha$

```
#Importing with custom names to avoid issues with numpy / sympy matrix
from cvxopt import matrix as cvxopt_matrix
from cvxopt import solvers as cvxopt_solvers

#Initializing values and computing H. Note the 1. to force to float type
m,n = X.shape
y = y.reshape(-1,1) * 1.
X_dash = y * X
H = np.dot(X_dash , X_dash.T) * 1.

#Converting into cvxopt format
P = cvxopt_matrix(H)
q = cvxopt_matrix(-np.ones((m, 1)))
G = cvxopt_matrix(-np.eye(m))
h = cvxopt_matrix(np.zeros(m))
A = cvxopt_matrix(y.reshape(1, -1))
b = cvxopt_matrix(np.zeros(1))

#Setting solver parameters (change default to decrease tolerance) 
cvxopt_solvers.options['show_progress'] = False
cvxopt_solvers.options['abstol'] = 1e-10
cvxopt_solvers.options['reltol'] = 1e-10
cvxopt_solvers.options['feastol'] = 1e-10

#Run solver
sol = cvxopt_solvers.qp(P, q, G, h, A, b)
alphas = np.array(sol['x'])
```

#### Compute $w$ and $b$ parameters

```
#w parameter in vectorized form
w = ((y * alphas).T @ X).reshape(-1,1)

#Selecting the set of indices S corresponding to non zero parameters
S = (alphas > 1e-4).flatten()

#Computing b
b = y[S] - np.dot(X[S], w)

#Display results
print('Alphas = ',alphas[alphas > 1e-4])
print('w = ', w.flatten())
print('b = ', b[0])
```

## Result

[image: SVM simple]

#### Source:

*Full code [here](https://xavierbourretsicotte.github.io/SVM_implementation.html)*

Answer (score 2):

here is my function it works on separable dataset

enjoy :)

```
def LMC(X, t, Xtest):
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import metrics

    #Compute alpha
    numSamples = len(X)

    P = matrix(outer(t,t) * inner(X,X))
    q = matrix(ones(numSamples) * -1)

    G = matrix(diag(ones(numSamples) * -1))
    h = matrix(zeros(numSamples))

    A = matrix(t, (1,numSamples))
    b = matrix(0.0)

    solution = solvers.qp(P, q, G, h, A, b)
    alpha=solution['x']

    Y=[] #prediction init
    B=[] #table B
    sv=[]#index of support vector
    plot(X[t==-1,0], X[t==-1,1], 'bx')
    plot(X[t==1,0], X[t==1,1], 'rx')
    #compute B
    for x in range(len(X)):
        b=t[x]
        for i in range(len(alpha)):        
            b-=alpha[i]*t[i]*sum([x * y for x, y in zip(X[i], X[x])])
            if alpha[i]>0.0001:
                if t[i]==-1:
                    plot(X[i,0], X[i,1], 'bo')
                else:
                    plot(X[i,0], X[i,1], 'ro')
                if not(i in sv):
                    sv.append(i)
        B.append(b)
    print("B equals "+str(mean(B)))
    for x in range(len(Xtest)):
        y=mean(B)
        for i in range(len(alpha)):        
            y+= alpha[i]*t[i]*sum([x * y for x, y in zip(X[i], Xtest[x])])
        Y.append(y)

    return Y,sv
```